# How to place model once in ARCore

Tags: arcore

In my code, the model gets rendered every time I tap the screen. I want that once the model is placed in AR, even if the user taps it should not place the second model. How can I do it? I am using ARcore.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if it is a native android or an UNITY ARCore project.The easiest logic will be to use a boolean like isPlaced (initially false). Once the model is placed in the AR scene, change the boolean to true.
have the Ontap functions logic in an if statement checking is isPlaced is false.

```
  bool isPlaced = false;
  // function to handle tap interaction
  ontapped(){
  if(!isPlaced){
  // logic to place model in AR Scene
      isPlaced = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Anchor anchor = hitresult.createAnchor();
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        TransformableNode lamp = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        lamp.getScaleController().setSensitivity(3);
        lamp.setParent(anchorNode);
        lamp.setRenderable(tanRenderable);
        lamp.select();
        ***arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(null)***;
```